# EF Core: one-to-one 'satellite' table needs its own key?

Tags: entity-framework-core

Here's my scenario:

```
public class Main
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public MoreDetail OptionalDetail { get; set; }
}

public class MoreDetail
{
    public Guid MainId { get; set; }
    public Main Main { get; set; }
    public string MoreInfo { get; set; }
}

// model building code:

mainBuilder.HasOne(m => m.OptionalDetail).WithOne(d => d.Main).IsRequired(false);
```

Intended:

- `MoreDetail` is an optional 'child' table of `Main`
- The primary key would be `MainId`; it doesn't need its own ID

Actual:

`The entity type 'Main' requires a key to be defined.`

Attempted:

- Adding `moreDetailBuilder.HasKey(d => d.MainId)`.  Yields the same error.
- Adding `.HasForeignKey<MoreDetail>(d => d.MainId)` to `Main` model builder code.  Gives `The foreign key {'MainId'} on entity type 'MoreDetail' cannot be marked as optional because it does not contain any property of a nullable type. Any foreign key can be marked as required, but only foreign keys with at least one property of a nullable type and which is not part of primary key can be marked as optional.`.
- Using `.IsRequired(true)` instead.  Key setup and inserting records works fine.. but at query time, EF Core generates an `INNER JOIN` which means nothing is returned if there are no records. :'(

The official docs example show the child/satellite table having its own primary key.  It just seems unnecessary; the data is completely identified by its foreign key, isn't it?